# What's the best practice to track a multilanguage website with more domains?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I own a multilanguage website hosted on 3 different domains.

- the MAIN one ( website.com )
- a subdomain ( en.website.com )
- russian one ( website.ru )

To properly track all the domains, I used the same Google Analytics ID and I created filters for each language. The aim is to have a global statistic (age, sex, etc...) and a single language profile to track each domain.
But today the client for whom I am working, told me that a friend (an SEO consultant, but i think he's just a friend) thinks my method is totally wrong and dangerous.

So the question is:
What's better - one ID with different profiles or a separate ID for each domain ?

Comment: I think it's best to create a different profile for each language/subdomain. You can then do roll-up reporting if you want to aggregate your data into something like an "all languages" report.

Comment: Do you mean using a different ID for each language? Wouldn't be better to just create a filter for each language?

Comment: @LorenzoPimps A profile is a subset of traffic from a given account ("ID") created using filters.  You should (almost) always have a profile that contains all traffic, no filters, since once a profile is created, you can't go backward in time if you mess up a filter.  You can typically find what you need by searching the complete profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to aggregate reporting or other tracking) across languages then a single iD using filters is the best way to go.  Not sure what would be "dangerous" about this.

As a former SEO consultant, I can say fairly, don't believe anything most SEO consultants say.  I think this is such a case -- your solution is a canonical case and great use for filtered profiles.

I have built several sites having a different but similar need -- each customer had their own site (a multi-tenant app) but we wanted to report customer traffic to them, while knowing aggregate traffic for us.  The filtering approach worked just fine, and we had several hundred of distinct customers.

Also, you can have both if you need it -- there's no reason you can't track multiple ids on the same site ... Technically, at least.  One of our customers had their own GA account so we just had the pages post to ours and their GA accounts.  I wouldn't recommend this, and not sure if Google is cool with it, but it worked, and afaik it's still working.